# Tile/Tilemap visibility odd glitch (Haxe + OpenFL)

Tags: visibility, haxe, tile, openfl

I took a sprite sheet of 7 frames (character running animation) and put it in a Tile array. For some strange reason, I can toggle the visibility of each frame (on or off) unless it is placed inside a conditional (if/then), in which case it stays on the scree even though the trace reveals that visibility is false. Any ideas why?

```
char[0].visible = false; //works!

s = 10;
if (s > 2) {
   char[0].visible = false; //trace's as false, but remains on screen
}
```

Comment: Your sample code looks fine, can you update your question with full isolated example that reproduces explained behaviour?

Comment: What target are you using? In any case (other than flash) rebuild your project and/or look to the target code if everything looks as it should there.